# An array can't be used in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, datatables

I have tried to make a table by using datatables with an array, but somehow it doesn't show the table on my html file.
The array is defined in my gs file as you can see in the code below.

It's a simple work but I'm still not sure what it went wrong.

```
var ssId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
var indexPage_sheetName = 'xxxxxxxx';
var valuesFromIndexPage = ss.getSheetByName(indexPage_sheetName).getDataRange().getValues();//array of 850rows×15cols
valuesFromIndexPage.shift();

function getData() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo-table").DataTable({
      data: valuesFromIndexPage
    });
  }); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="foo-table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

@ZektorH Here's the console log of running my code.

```
userCodeAppPanel:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at initializeTable (userCodeAppPanel:9)
    at af (4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:67)
    at 4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:10
    at ng.J (4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:94)
    at Hd (4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:42)
    at Dd (4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:43)
    at Bd.b (4105580746-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ja.js:39)
```

I looked again at my data and I found out the data became null on console.log(but it has data when I see it on Logger.log).
I'm posting what I did and got below.

```
function getData() {
  Logger.log(valuesFromIndexPage); //the array is in valuesFromIndexPage
  return valuesFromIndexPage;
}
```

```
        function initializeTable(data) {
        console.log(data); //it returns null here...
            var aDataSet = data.slice(1);
```

- The log from Logger.log

[19-10-31 09:47:00:116 JST] [[ID, 案件名, .......

@ZektorH These're the whole codes without data.

code.gs

```
var ssId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);

var indexPage_sheetName = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var valuesFromIndexPage = ss.getSheetByName(indexPage_sheetName).getDataRange().getValues();


function createSidebar() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle('My custom sidebar').setWidth(300))
}

function getData() {
  return valuesFromIndexPage;
}



function doGet(e) {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('title');
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("ready!");
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeTable).getData(); //calls the getData funciton from Apps Script and returns the results to the initializeTable function
        });

        function initializeTable(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var aDataSet = data.slice(1); // all except header
            var head = []; // headers
            data[0].forEach(function(e) {
                head.push({
                    'sTitle': e
                });
            });
            $('#foo-table').dataTable({
                "aaData": aDataSet,
                "aoColumns": head
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="foo-table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check the logs in console and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Chage with `columns` of of key in dataTable for table headers and chage `$("#foo-table").DataTable` at `$("#foo-table").dataTable`

```js
var valuesFromIndexPage=[{"free-text-c1":"free-text-r1","c2":"r1","c3":"r1","c4":"r1","c5":"r1","c6":"r1","c7":"r1","c8":"r1","c9":"free-text-r1","c10":"free-text-r1"},{"free-text-c1":"free-text-r2","c2":"r2","c3":"r2","c4":"r2","c5":"r2","c6":"r2","c7":"r2","c8":"r2","c9":"free-text-r2","c10":"free-text-r2"}];

valuesFromIndexPage.shift();

function getData() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo-table").dataTable({
      destroy: true,
      scrollX: true,
      data: valuesFromIndexPage,
      columns: _.keys(valuesFromIndexPage[0]).map((key) => { return { "title": key, "data": key } })
    });
  }); 
}

getData()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="foo-table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: it has syntax error on the line

columns: _.keys(valuesFromIndexPage[0]).map((key) => { return { "title": key, "data": key } })
any help?

Comment: did you include `lodash` as external libraries? and also check `valuesFromIndexPage` array length

Comment: I did include lodash. What about the array length? Should I edit keys(valuesFromIndexPage[0]) to keys(valuesFromIndexPage[valuesFromIndexPage.length])?

Comment: Could you share the `Object` of `valuesFromIndexPage[ valuesFromIndexPage.length -  1 ]` and `valuesFromIndexPage[ 0 ]` . ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using it on a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars), I was able to get it to work like this:

Apps Script

```
function createSidebar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle('My custom sidebar').setWidth(300))
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("ready!");
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeTable).getData(); //calls the getData funciton from Apps Script and returns the results to the initializeTable function
        });

        function initializeTable(data) {
            var aDataSet = data.slice(1); // all except header
            var head = []; // headers
            data[0].forEach(function(e) {
                head.push({
                    'sTitle': e
                });
            });
            $('#foo-table').dataTable({
                "aaData": aDataSet,
                "aoColumns": head
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="foo-table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I copied all your codes except createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar') to the name of my html file, and return value of getData function to my actual data, but still doesn't show anything on my screen. it's totally blanc page...
just to make it sure, I typed "a"in the body of html, and it showed up so I'm guessing something's wrong in the script tab...

Comment: @leaN5525 could you attach the logs of your browser (after you launch the sidebar) into your question? To get the browser logs press F12 then go to the tab "Console".

Comment: I re-posted what I found so far

Comment: @leaN5525 could you please make a copy of your project, remove all sensitive data and share it with us?

Comment: I added what I have in the question.